# Changing URLs when using $_get to determine webpage

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently use `$_GET['base']` to determine which homepage that the user visits.

This results in `localhost/?base=administrator` or `localhost/?base=guest`

I am also using this to control which page is the user at, such as
`localhost/?base=guest&page=register`

Is there any way to use mod_rewrite, or htaccess, to change how this system works?
Modifying my code is not an issue, is this possible?

EDIT:

I am trying to achive this:

`localhost/?base=guest` to `localhost/guest`
`localhost/?base=admin` to `localhost/admin`
`localhost/?base=guest&page=register` to `localhost/guest/register`

Below is my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?base=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?base=$1 [L]
```

Will the document path affect how it is being called? As I am using a `case` loop to include which items are needed.

This, however, works for `localhost`, but it will loop every other address to main.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?base=guest[L]
```

But did not give a result as expected.

Comment: Not entirely sure what the question is, but yes, `.htaccess` / `mod_rewrite` are often used to redirect / send people different places depending on parameters in the URL.

Comment: Tried a few of the mods, but doesn't really changes anything. Will update the question

Comment: @Ctc can you explain better what you want to achieve? for example: I want `localhost/guest/register` to redirect `localhost/?base=guest&page=register` something like this

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili Thanks for the suggestion. Edited as stated.

Comment: Welcome, I've posted answer you can check if it's working

Answer (score 1):

Your rules in .htaccess need to be in reverse order, like below:

`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?base=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?base=$1 [L]`

That is because if it is kept in the order you have it, both `localhost/?base=guest&page=register` & `localhost/?base=administrator` will match the rule `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?base=$1`.

Having them in reverse order ensures that the first rule is matched only for `localhost/?base=guest&page=register`. It won't match the first rule for `localhost/?base=administrator`. I hope that helps.

Comment: This made sense, but I received a error 500 afterwards.

Comment: Please make sure you don't copy the empty spaces, etc. from the above code I pasted. What URL you are trying to access which gives you a 500 error?

Comment: accessing localhost will give a 500, localhost/guest will also return a 500

Answer (score 1):

So you can use this simple code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?base=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)$ index.php?base=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

`\w` will match symbols `a-z`, `0-9` and underscore `_`, I think those characters are enough for your case, but if you need expansion it will be easy

Also in this case you don't need to change your code, because you still get `base` and `page` parameters in the `$_GET` array

**UPDATE:**

to disable query string params `page` and `base` (other params may be needed) add these two lines to the code at the bottom:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\?|&)(page|base) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: This works when accessing `localhost/guest` and `localhost/guest/register`, but accessing `localhost/?base=guest&page=register`, it will still be the same, is there any way to redirect it completely? an upvote for the answer though.

Comment: I've updated it, but disabled only base, and page params from get var, but if you want we can disable query string at all (passing any param within url)

Comment: The incomming request is `/?base=`  or `/?base=foobar&page=` , your pattern doesnt  match the second one, also why are you redirecting it to 404?

Comment: @starkeen it works indeed, I'm redirecting to 404 because no direct access to /?base=foobar&page= something like this, only rewritten url works

Comment: Yes, it works. But instead of redirecting the real uri to 404 ,you can 301 redirect it back to the new url it's good for seo.

Comment: Also seo recommend not to make redirects

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude your existent files and folders from the rule

```
RewriteEngine On
# if the request is a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
# or file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
#do nothing
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?base=$1&page=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?base=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This works as well, thanks for the comments, learnt slightly.

Comment: @starkeen: What does `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` do?

Comment: This line says "Do not rewrite the uri" .